# Google Earth Engine Image (Error) User memory limit exceeded. How can I fix it?

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, image-mosaic

This is the code that has an error. I don´t know how to fix it.

I am trying to get the albedo values of a range of time: 2001-2018 and just of 4 months of each year, September to December.

```
var col = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD43A3')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2001-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
                  .filterBounds(geometry).select('Albedo_WSA_shortwave'); 
                   
// Functions to stack colletion series into image bands 

var stackCollection = function(collection) {
  var first = ee.Image(collection.first()).select([]);
  var appendBands = function(image, previous) 
  {return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);};
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBands, first));};

// Function to generate mask for each Scene.

var getSceneMask = function(scene) {
  var dateString = ee.Date(scene.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
  var mask = scene.select('Albedo_WSA_shortwave').gt(-9999).updateMask(ee.Image(1)); 
  return mask.rename(dateString);};

//Stacked mask for collection
    
var Maskcol = stackCollection(col.map(getSceneMask));

// Generate a datelist for collection 

var datelist = ee.List(Maskcol.bandNames()).map(function(date){return ee.Date(date).format('yyyy-MM-dd')});

// Stack bands and rename by date  

var WSA_stacked = stackCollection(col.select('Albedo_WSA_shortwave')).multiply(0.001).rename(datelist).clip(geometry);


Map.addLayer(WSA_stacked.select(20), {min:0.0, max:400, gamma:2}); 

print(WSA_stacked);
print(datelist);

// Exportar datos //

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: WSA_stacked.clip(geometry),
  description: 'MODIS_WSA_stacked',
  region: geometry,
  folder: 'ejemplo',
  scale: 500,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326'});
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to state, in words, what you are trying to accomplish. Since it reports a memory error, reporting the amount of RAM on your system, and the amount used by the process is strongly recommended. An indication of *where* in the code the error occurs is also necessary.

Comment: @Vince While I agree that a detailed problem statement is good practice, please note that in [tag:google-earth-engine] the computation does not execute on the user's computer, and there are no options to vary the amount of RAM available to the server performing the computation — it's “one size fits all".

Comment: @val Note that this produces an image with 6569 bands - depending on the size of your geometry, the export could be large and difficult to deal with. What is the end goal - can you process the data further in EE before export - some kind of reduction maybe?

Comment: I need the values of albedo between 2001 and 2018 for 4 months, (sept-dec) but I don´t know hoy to filter for this dates on each year.

Answer (score 3):

Your `stackCollection` function is an inefficient way to go about combining an image collection's bands into an image, and is not needed. You can use the built-in `ImageCollection.toBands()`, instead. It produces band names of the form "imageId_bandName" so we'll have to reformat the strings, but the image IDs are already the dates, so we don't have to save the `system:time_start` separately, just change the text format.

```
var col = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD43A3')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2001-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .select('Albedo_WSA_shortwave'); 

var colStacked = col.toBands();

var datelist = colStacked.bandNames().map(function(bandName){
  // Band names from toBands are of the form "imageId_bandName",
  // so in this case they are the date with underscores followed by "_Albedo_WSA_shortwave".
  // Match the underscores, replace them with dashes, and discard the rest.
  return ee.String(bandName).replace("^(\\d+)_(\\d+)_(\\d+)_.*$", "$1-$2-$3");
});

// Or, instead of using the image IDs we can use system:time_start from the
// collection. This computes the same value; use whichever you like.
var datelist2 =
  ee.List(
    col.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['system:time_start']).get('list'))
  .map(function(timestamp) {
    return ee.Date(timestamp).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
  });

// Stack bands and rename bands by date  
var WSA_stacked = colStacked
  .multiply(0.001)
  .rename(datelist)
  .clip(geometry);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0bfc7bc140517ffd157e8e9862f23e42

Note that I left out your `getSceneMask` because the only part of it that was actually used in your script was the band names. If you intended to mask the images, I recommend doing it in a `.map()` rather than building a separate collection and image and list, i.e. change `col` rather than the later steps.

I also removed several redundant `.select()`s — the one in the definition of `col` is all that is necessary.

Comment: I get lost in this part:


 return ee.String(bandName).replace("^(\\d+)_(\\d+)_(\\d+)_.*$", "$1-$2-$3");
});

Comment: @val Reasonable — regular expressions are a great tool but they can be cryptic. I've added an alternative that uses the date formatting like your original code did,